# Wireless Repeater causing kernel to crash

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, kernel, crash

So my wireless set up is not ideal as far as my location relative to my AP goes.

However I recently remembered I had/dug up an Amped Wireless 300N repeater (range extender).

I set it up in my living room, and the results have been wonderful, however, on my personal linux box, my computer will randomly just crash!

No crashes to date on any of the other machines connected to that repeater. (They are all windows except for mine)

The output ends with:

```
RIP [<ffffffff8131f2a9>] scatterwalk_start.part.5+0x9/0x10
RSP <ffff8801bed03898>
Kernel panic -not syncing: Fatal execption in interrupt
drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04

heres the link to the repeater's product page: http://www.ampedwireless.com/support/model/sr300.html

The crash usually occurs when trying to connect/disconnect (which it sometimes does itself as it will intermittently loose signal for a moment or so)

I have pics of the entire output, as soon as I find my SD card adapter, I can upload them.

I'm really just wondering if anyone has experienced a similar problem in the past or can point me in the right direction as I have no networking knowledge whatsoever and don't really know where to start.

Thanks all

**EDIT: updated my firmware and things are looking good, that might have been the trick. I suppose time will tell.**